Generating SHA512withRsa using java
I am trying to sign my payload using SHA512withRsa but I am facing issues while verifying the  signature can anyone please help me
I want to know what is going wrong in my code  is my  generating signature code wrong or verifying code wrong
Code for signing my payload
public String generateSignature() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, UnrecoverableKeyException,
    KeyStoreException {

    KeyStore keystore = getPrivateKeystore(privateKeyPath, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
    PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPassword.toCharArray(), keystore);

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA512", "BC");
    byte[] newDigest = digest.digest(data);

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA/PSS", "BC");
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(newDigest);

    byte[] sign = signature.sign();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(sign));

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sign);
}

code for verifying signature
public boolean verifySignature(String payload, String signature) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, UnrecoverableKeyException,
    KeyStoreException {

    Signature ver = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA/PSS", "BC");
    ver.initVerify(getPublicKey(publicKeyAlias, keystore));
    ver.update(payload.getBytes());

    byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(decode));

    boolean verify = ver.verify(decode);
    System.out.println(verify);

    return verify;
}

I tried signing my payload with SHA512withRSA algo but I am not able to verify .
I just want to know where I am making mistake is it in my genertaing signature code or verifying code

Indicate source code here by either indenting all lines four spaces or wrapping in a pair of lines with three back-tick marks. I tried to improve your code formatting, but still needs more work.

When signing, it is hashed twice (implicitly and explicitly), whereas when verifying, it is only hashed once (implicitly). Remove the explicit hashing when signing.
